# "lxml not found, please install it" error on Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colaboratory. While calling `pandas.read_html`, I am getting an import error. I have installed lxml via pip and I can see it installed in right directory, but I am still getting this error. I have tried restarting the server but nothing useful happened.

Comment: What operating system / Python version are you using?

Comment: 3.6. I am using online notebook server. https://colab.research.google.com

Comment: Did you use pip3 install lxml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please remember that if you're using python2 you will have to install lxml using:

```
pip install lxml
```

If you are using python3 you will have to use:

```
pip3 install lxml
```

Comment: Hoorray! Have fun :)

Comment: That didn't worked for me :/. `Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (4.2.3)` error : `FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?`

Comment: Ok: you have to restart execution environment before it works